# Rendering 1.2 GB of textures smoothly, how does a 1 GB GPU do this?

Tags: opengl, textures, gpu

My goal is to see what would happen when using more texture data than what would fit in physical GPU memory. My first attempt was to load up to 40 DDS textures, resulting in a memory footprint way higher than there was GPU memory. However, my scene would still render at 200+ fps on a 9500 GT.

My conclusion: the GPU/OpenGL is being smart and only keeps certain parts of the mipmaps in memory. I thought that should not be possible on a standard config, but whatever.

Second attempt: disable mip mapping, such that the GPU will always have to sample from the high res textures. Once again, I loaded about 40 DDS textures in memory. I verified the texture memory usage with gDEBugger: 1.2 GB. Still, my scene was rendering at 200+ fps.

The only thing I noticed was that when looking away with the camera and then centering it once again on the scene, a serious lag would occur. As if only then it would transfer textures from main memory to the GPU. (I have some basic frustum culling enabled)

*My question: what is going on? How does this 1 GB GPU manage to sample from 1.2 GB of texture data at 200+ fps?*

Comment: Maybe part of the texture is in GPU mem and part of it in RAM? Maybe you have shared memory between CPU and GPU? Maybe PCI express is just that fast?

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL can page complete textures in and out of texture memory in between draw-calls (not just in between frames). Only those needed for the current draw-call actually need to be resident in graphics memory, the others can just reside in system RAM. It likely only does this with a very small subset of your texture data. It's pretty much the same as any cache - how can you run algorithms on GBs of data when you only have MBs of cache on your CPU?

Also PCI-E busses have a very high throughput, so you don't really notice that the driver does the paging.

If you want to verify this, `glAreTexturesResident` might or might-not help, depending on how well the driver is implemented.

Comment: Sounds plausible. One useful test would then be to load even more textures, putting a decent load on the PCI-E bus. The lag I experience when changing viewpoints, could it be related to OpenGL being dumb and prematurely freeing too much texture memory? The situation is: 40 visible textures (smooth), no visible textures (smooth), 40 visible textures (1 very long frame, smooth afterwards).

Comment: Anything on this is just speculation. There are probably cache replacement strategies that could cause this, yes - for example an "untrained" cache might default to something similar to LRU, which is the worst possible config if you're just cycling through your data. If you want answers, you have to check with your hardware/driver manufacturer - different configs might give you completely different effects.

Comment: On the other hand, with 1.2gb of texture data, at least 200 mb would have to be reloaded each frame. At 200FPS, this would mean 200x200 mb/s would max out every existing PCI-E bus.

Comment: edit: indeed, exactly what I also just realized. Anyway, I will do some more tests. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When zoomed in, such that the 40 textures are still being rendered while filling as much of the screen as possible, I get around 160 fps. Zoomed out, lowering area covered by the textures by about factor 4, the framerate is about 250 fps. In both cases there is this 1.2 GB of textures visible on the screen, sampled without mip mapping. There is clearly some kind of optimization being done.

Comment: Paging can probably happen a lot more fine-grained than individual pages. I expect that newer drivers/cards do this, especially w.r.t. GPGPU tasks. In the case were you zoom out, some of the pages might never be hit, and so they are not paged in, actually decreasing the amount of memory that the GPU uses.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you were forcing texture thrashing in your test (discarding and uploading of some textures from system memory to GPU memory every frame), which I'm not sure you are, modern GPUs and PCI-E have such a huge bandwidth that some thrashing does impact performance that much. One of the 9500GT models is quoted to have a bandwidth of 25.6 GB/s, and 16x PCI-E slots (500 MB/s x 16 = 8 GB/s) are the norm.

As for the lag, I would assume the GPU + CPU throttle down their power usage when you aren't drawing visible textures, and when you suddenly overload them they need a brief instant to power up. In real life apps and games this 0%-100% sudden workload changes never happen, so a slight lag is totally understandable and expected, I guess.